# Compilation difference between gcc4 and gcc7, static and dynamic/shared library

Tags: c++, gcc

I have an app that links a library using the C++ runtime.

On Centos7, the default gcc is **4.8.5**. My development build machine uses Centos 7 with the `devtoolset-7`, **gcc 7.3.1**.

#### Static library

```
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                        | App compiled and linked with GCC7 | App compiled and linked with GCC4 |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Lib compiled with GCC7 | WORKS                             | DOESN'T WORK                      |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Lib compiled with GCC4 | WORKS                             | WORKS                             |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

#### Shared/Dynamic library

No issue to use **GCC 4** to compile an app and link a shared/dynamic library compiled with **GCC 7**.

#### CMake

- The libraries are compiled using CMake with `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`
- The app is compiled using directly g++: `g++ -std=c++11 app.cpp -L. -llibMylib -Iinclude`
- By default:

```
// g++ 7
$ g++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep -F __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 201402L
// g++ 4
$ g++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep -F __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 199711L
```

Question:

- Why is there a different behavior?

Comment:

- It shouldn't be a problem of ABI because Centos 7 supports the old ABI for both, the default gcc 4 and the devtoolset 7.

  - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/10/html-single/user_guide/index#sect-GCC-CPP-Compatibility
  - https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/10/08/migrating-c-and-c-applications-from-red-hat-enterprise-linux-version-7-to-version-8#

Comment: Are you using the same C++ version in both compiler calls? Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: C++11, I edited the question. I get `undefined reference to`, I'll try it again and update the question.